# Geoserver netcdf plugin to publish nc file - raster values wrong

Tags: geoserver

the following image shows the geoserver i used[image]I used netcdf plugin to publish a nc file. I use wms to access it (see following picture for result), but I found that the value of the raster is wrong.

[image]

Another picture of the same nc file opened by the PanoplyWin (a pro nc software):

[image]

This is the structure of the nc file:

[image]

Visualization of mean Daily relative humidity given a specific time and a specific level. The mean daily relative humidity value is between 0 and 100, but the as shown above an example value is -26891, out of this range.

Answer (score 1):

The dataset is stored as packed data, GeoServer does not un-pack it by default.
Add the following system variable on the Java virtual machine running GeoServer to make it unpack the data:

> -Dorg.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.enhance.ScaleMissing=true

E.g., if GeoServer is deplyed in Tomcat, you'd add it in the catalina.sh or setenv.sh as part of the JVM_OPTS.

Comment: thanks for your advice,but i am not familiar with JVM  and i install geoserver by the package of windows installer. can you tell me where to add the system variable in my condition.thank you so much